# openOrCreateDatabase in a Thread

Tags: android, sql, multithreading

In my main class (MainActivity.java) I call a new Thread which does a HttpResponse and from the result of that response I create a database and populate it with the HttpResponce.

This works perfectly in the my main class (MainActivity.java). The problem is I have multiple Threads and the main class (MainActivity.java) is getting cluttered, and when I try and create another class (Class2.java) for the Thread I get an error trying to create the database using openOrCreateDatabase().

here is my code:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        class2.execute();
    }
}
```

Class2.java

```
public class lvl3 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try{
        //this is the HTTPRequest that works
    }
    try
    {
        // this is the problem
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following with the following errors:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable


SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type Class2

SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE , null);
The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, DatabaseErrorHandler) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, null)

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE , null);
MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", null);
```

Program runs but I get a few errors here are just a few:

```
12-31 10:22:33.116: E/SQLiteLog(2045): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-31 10:22:33.126: E/SQLiteLog(2045): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(//MyDB) - 
12-31 10:22:33.136: E/SQLiteDatabase(2045): Failed to open database 'MyDB'.
12-31 10:22:33.136: E/SQLiteDatabase(2045): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
12-31 10:22:33.136: E/SQLiteDatabase(2045):     at com.example.matthew28project.Class2.doInBackground(Class2.java:57)
12-31 10:22:33.136: E/SQLiteDatabase(2045):     at com.example.matthew28project.Class2.doInBackground(Class2.java:1)
12-31 10:22:33.136: E/SQLiteDatabase(2045):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-31 10:22:33.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-31 10:22:33.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-31 10:22:33.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-31 10:22:33.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.example.matthew28project.Class2.doInBackground(Class2.java:57)
12-31 10:22:33.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.example.matthew28project.Class2.doInBackground(Class2.java:1)`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your import statements and post `Class2` java code coz i see lvl3 not Class2 `public class lvl3`

Comment: Sorry I changed the name of the Class to make it easier to read. It should be edited correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to have a subcalss of SQLiteOpenHelper using the registry of singleton pattern to manage your SQLite database, you may start with the following code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Instances
    private static HashMap<Context, MySQLiteOpenHelper> mInstances;

    // Member object
    private Context mContext;

    // Database metadata
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MySQLiteOpenHelper.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Table names
    public static final String TABLE_ONE = "TABLE_ONE";
    public static final String TABLE_TWO = "TABLE_TWO";

    // Create table querys
    private static final String QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_ONE = String.format(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (" +
                    "`%s` INTEGER primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "`%s` INTEGER, " +
                    "`%s` INTEGER, " +
            ");",
            TABLE_ONE,
            "column_one", "column_two", "column_three");

    private static final String QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_TWO = String.format(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (" +
                    "`%s` INTEGER primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "`%s` INTEGER, " +
                    "`%s` INTEGER, " +
            ");",
            TABLE_TWO,
            "column_one", "column_two", "column_three");

    private MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        mContext = context;
    }

    public static MySQLiteOpenHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if(mInstances == null)
            mInstances = new HashMap<Context, MySQLiteOpenHelper>();

        if(mInstances.get(context) == null)
            mInstances.put(context, new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context));

        return mInstances.get(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_ONE);
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_TWO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //TODO Upgrade your database here

    }

}
```

After that, you can create your own database access command pattern by obtaining the SQLiteDatabaseOpenHelper and SQLiteDatabase as below.

```
MySQLiteOpenHelper mySQLiteOpenHelper = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance(context);
mySQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

If you still get stuck in multi-threading environment, you may try overriding the getReadableDatabase method as a synchronized method in the subclass of SQLiteDatabaseOpenHelper.

```
@Override
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    return super.getReadableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: After a few tweaks to your code I was able to get it to work. Thanks!